# Can an organizational account (office 365) be used for live/Microsoft services?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365, microsoft-account, azure-machine-learning-service

I understand that Office 365 is on separate domain and live id (Microsoft account) is used for consumer applications.

But can an Office 365 account get live/Microsoft services?

The issue is we trying to SSO Office 365 applications and Azure ML (used with Microsoft account) but as the domains are different I am unable to find any proper help or process on the web.

We can create a live account with our company domain but can we create a federation on Live account ? For e.g. on Office 365 we created a @.com federation and were able to SSO it, how can we do the same with a live account ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Azure ML [pricing page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/machine-learning/) the free tier is standalone, requiring a Live ID.  The Standard tier is associated with your Azure subscription, so you use your org IDs.

Comment: We can create a live account with our company domain but can we create a federation on Live account ? For e.g. on Office 365 we created a @<Company>.com federation and were able to SSO it, how can we do the same with a live account ?

Comment: You can add the live account to your Azure Active Directory, but you cannot associate it with a federated identity.

Comment: Can we SSO the live account by SAML or any other form of claims authentication ?

Comment: You might be able to do that with ACS; I'm not sure.  I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that supporting multiple identity providers for a single identity was on Microsoft's roadmap as well.